# Android IPC: onServiceConnected called, followed by NullPointerException

Tags: android, service, nullpointerexception, ipc, aidl

Our application connects to IPC `Service` exposed via AIDL interface. Everything worked fine up until now, but suddenly we observed a NullPointerException being thrown right after invocation of `onServiceConnected` callback.

We bind to the service in the following way:

```
boolean isServiceBound = context.bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Then we ensure that the service was bound successfully and a background thread waits for `onServiceConnected` callback to be invoked:

```
private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                   IBinder binder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "converting Binder into IAidlService");

        aidlService = IAidlService.Stub.asInterface(binder);

        serviceConnected(); // this call releases background thread that waits for connection to be established

    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IAidlService disconnected unexpectedly");

        aidlService = null;
    }
};
```

Once `serviceConnected()` is called during invocation of `onServiceConnected` callback, we assume that the connection was established and `aidlService` variable was initialized (unless `onServiceDisconnected` gets invoked afterwards, but it is not the case here).

As I said, this scheme worked fine for some time, but suddenly we encountered NullPointerException being thrown right after `onServiceConnected`. Logcat output:

```
01-21 14:06:32.717 22651-22651/com.xxx.xxx D/LocalService: converting Binder into IAidlService
01-21 14:06:32.721 22651-9574/com.xxx.xxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[LocalService]
01-21 14:06:32.721 22651-9574/com.xxx.xxx E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.xxx.xxx, PID: 22651
01-21 14:06:32.721 22651-9574/com.xxx.xxx E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.yyy.yyy.IAidlService.someMethod(android.os.Bundle)' on a null object reference
```

As you can see, `aidlService` is used in background thread after `onServiceConnected` was invoked on main thread. I'm 99.9% confident that there is no multi-threading issue here and the logic that makes the background thread wait until `serviceConnected()` is called works fine (and the 4ms delay seen in logcat supports this claim).

We couldn't reproduce this behavior.

So, we know that `onServiceConnected` was called, but `aidlService` variable wasn't initialized. I see only one potential cause for this behavior: `IBinder` object passed to `onServiceConnected` by the system was `null` (I'm 100% confident that the object returned in `onBind()` of an IPC service was valid)

I couldn't find any information regarding this scenario on the web, therefore my questions are:

1. Have anyone encountered a similar behavior?
2. Are there any scenarios in which `onServiceConnected` will be passed `null` as second parameter instead of a valid `IBinder` returned by remote `Service`?

Comment: what stops you to step-in into `IAidlService.Stub.asInterface()` method with the debugger?

Comment: @pskink, this code is auto generated and I investigated it. Could you explain what will I get by stepping through it with debugger given that the bug is not reproducible?

Comment: if you investigated it then you probably noticed that `asInterface(android.os.IBinder obj)` can return `null` only if `obj` is null

Comment: but if you don't trust `AIDL` generated code, you don't have to use `AIDL` at all and still perform secure transactions on remote objects, all
you need is to use a raw `Binder` API to implement your own custom RPC protocol

Comment: @pskink, I see what you're saying - I was a bit confused by the Proxy part of Stub, but now I realize that `asInterface` indeed returns `null` only in case of `null` parameter. I will edit the question in order to narrow down the scope. Thanks

Comment: ad 2) see [this](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/LoadedApk.java#1222)

Comment: @pskink, are you trying to say that under no circumstances could `onServiceConnected()` be called with null parameter?

Comment: this is the only code i found where `onServiceConnected` is called,  so the answer is: you have to find a bug in your code if you still have NPE

Comment: @pskink, agree. We will go back to "99.9% confidence logic" and search for a bug there. Thanks for the help. Could you post your comments as answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @pskink's help I realized that neither `onServiceConnected` can be called with null `IBinder`, nor AIDL's `Stub.asInterface` can return null.

Bottom line: no need for null checks in `onServiceConnected` callback.